# Angular add service to multiple modules at once

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, angular-module

I have a module that has a service defined as

```
angular.module('mean.system').service('helperService', ['$rootScope', '$q', '$log', function ($rootScope, $q, $log) {
```

I am defining another module that will use the same service. I want to inject this service into another module, is it valid to do something like

```
angular.module('mean.system', 'myModule2').service('helperService', ... (etc) ) {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that case you should identify and separate all the shared parts of your app (services, controllers, directives, etc) and put them in their own module:

```
angular.module('shared.services').service('helperService', ... (etc) )...
```

And then inject that shared module in the modules that need them:

```
angular.module('mean.system', ['shared.services', other-dependencies...])
angular.module('myModule2', ['shared.services', other-dependencies...])
```

This way you can use the `helperService` (and all other parts added to the `shared.services` module) in your other modules.